# Extra Inputs to Pipeline

Tags: apache-beam

We are trying to build an application using BEAM as our transformation API. Currently we are running in an issue, and would appreciate if someone can point us to in the right direction.
Here is our use case.
1. We are processing a file, which needs to call the database and then replace the value with the key. This code works fine. 
2. We have some business logic where if asked for cached, then we should load the complete key/values in a map and provide it to the PCollection. This is where we are struggling. 
We would really appreciate, if you someone could guide us in the right direction. 
If this is not the correct forum could you please let us know where we can post such questions.

Thank you

Comment: It is not entirely clear from your question, but would something like side-inputs help? See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs

Comment: Anton,Thank you for your advice. I am trying to use Side-Inputs now. But am not sure if it would run in Spark. 
for simplicity let me explain what we are trying to achieve. We are trying to load a ResultSet as a map of objects in Cache and use it in subsequent piplelines. Something like a session variable. Can we do it, and what are the performance implications?